# React router url changes correctly but component not being rendered from button component link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I have something similar to the following [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-engelbart-mn4z4?file=/src/index.js:493-508) example where I need to use react routing within two different components.

The problem that I am facing is that, if using this codesandbox example and I click down to either the `Profile` or `Quotes` component level and assuming I have the following Material-UI button within each of these bottom components:

```
            <Button>
                text="New Item"
                variant="outlined"
                className={classes.newButton}
                component={NewItem} 
                to={'/new-item'}
            </Button>
```

When clicking on this "New Item" button, the URL changes to the correct route, i.e. `/new-item` but the actual `NewItem` component is not being rendered in the page?

If I refresh the browser, then it loads correctly.

Can anyone pls assist with the above and what the best solution is, when at this level?

Comment: must use link there

Answer (score 0):

Arthur, make sure in your index.js or wherever you are declaring your switch its set up like so.

```
<Switch>
      <Route exact path="/NewItem" component={NewItem}/>
</Switch>
```

Then you can simply add a nav link like so

```
<Link to="/NewItem">New Item</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

the button will have a component of `Link` which is imported from `react-router-dom`

```
 <Button>
        text="New Item"
        variant="outlined"
        className={classes.newButton}
        component={Link} 
        to="/new-item"
 </Button>
```

and in the `app.js` you will create a `Route` like so :

```
<Switch>
      <Route exact path="/NewItem" component={NewItem}/>
</Switch>
```

Comment: I actually tried this but this actually rendered the component `NewItem` within the `Home` component and not right back at App.js level. Any ideas pls?

Comment: is your route like this: ` <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />` sounds like you are missing an `exact`

Answer (score 0):

Well you shouldn't use button for changing go to new Page or going new URL. rather than use
`<link to=""/>` for routing but if you want to use button for going to different page than use Redirect from `react-router-dom`

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
    const Next = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    return <Redirect to='/NewItem' />;
    };
    <Button onClick={Next}>
         text="New Item" variant="outlined" className={classes.newButton}
         component={NewItem}
    </Button>;
```

Or you can use Link using `Link`

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
    
    <Link to={'/NewItem'} className={classes.newButton}>
         New Item
    </Link>;
```

Comment: Tried this and received the error: `TypeError: e.preventdefault is not a function` Any ideas pls?

Comment: I also tried the `Link` and unfortunately that also didn't work. Not sure if people don't realise but I am actually three levels down as I have `<BrowserRoute>` in two separate components. I need to somehow push this redirect or link to, to parent level.

Comment: Yes sorry it's was a small mistake i have edited. it should be  `e.preventDefault();`. if it still does not work can you add the app.js file or file where you are applying `<BrowserRoute>`